# Disable of PDB for large project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

how to disable PDB in Visual Studio ?
As i understand, my project has more than 4096 files for linker. And `Project Property -> Linker -> Debugging` as i understand, would disable all debug information in Debugger window and i can`t see variables values.

Error text:

> Error: too many modules for program database

What can i do? Project totally don't run in debug mode more cause too large, but pdb file is only 200MB.

I can disable pdb by turn off `Generate Debug Info`, but I need debug info while development.

Comment: If your project has that many files, I would worry about that instead of how to disable generation of debug-info. Do you really *need* that many files in a single project? Can't you split it up into multiple projects (like a set of libraries or DLL's)? Building your project must take *ages*, dividing into sub-projects using libraries or utility programs of some kind or other will speed up things considerably, as well as allowing you to actually be able to debug your application(s).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg but it already done. I have one solution and seven projects that build dll and lib's to one project. But it's still talking about size

Comment: This [Knowledge Base article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/238875) lists a number of options.

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks. I would try them all and write there after results

Comment: You may also not use VS for compiling, but write a bat script with commands for cl.exe (it is not very complicated thing) and add there special line to remove *.pdb files. As an option. Or use cmake.

Comment: How many cpp files does your project have? If much less than 4096, try to link all your dependencies as dynamic libraries (dlls) rather than static libraries (libs).

Comment: If more than 4096 cpp files, than as many other people say break your project into several projects. Or just include several cpp-s into one large cpp file.

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is that there are just too many modules for the linker, you may be able to resolve the issue by reducing the number of modules by breaking your project into multiple projects. The projects could still be in the same solution, just separate projects. The sub projects could either generate a static library or a DLL, depending on your needs. Though if you're on Windows then DLLs are generally preferred. This should allow you to generate usable PDBs for your existing project.

This also gives the option of turning off PDBs for each library individually.

Answer (score 0):

If you do extensive changes to your projects, don't forget to delete the PDB-files. Visual Studio creates them incrementally (to make it faster, I guess), so old stuff is never removed from PDB-files. This can pile up against the 4096-file limitation.

Delete the PDB-file, and let Visual Studio build it from scratch; there is a chance it will succeed. As far as I understand, PDB-file is not removed if you do rebuild, so you really have to delete it, and not do clean/rebuild.

---

If the limitation is real and not transient like this, some solutions suggested by other people are:

- Convert static libs to DLLs - each DLL has its own PDB-file
- Disable debug info where you never need it